# Why is my dynamically-added content not rendering with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I'm using jQuery Mobile + Backbone + RequireJS. After successful login I do the following:

```
require(['app/view/main'], function(MainView) {
  var mainView = new MainView();
  $('body').html(mainView.render().el);
});
```

and render() looks like

```
render: function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template);
  return this;
}
```

Upon doing so, my page is blank. Inspecting the body, I do see the following HTML inside the body:

```
<div data-role="page" id="main">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
      <h1>Accounts</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    hello
  </div>
</div>
```

I've also tried doing this inside render():

```
this.$el.html(this.template).trigger('create');
```

as well as

```
this.$el.html(this.template).page();
```

but the page is still blank. Any ideas why?

If I simply put the HTML inside the body and load the page, it displays fine, like a normal jQuery Mobile app would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you waiting until after pageinit to trigger / create your page?

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    // trigger
});
```

Also, jQM may be interpreting your markup as a single page template and then by injecting a `data-role='page'` element, you are marking up a multiple page document (with only a single page). Try leaving the `<div data-role='page'>` element in your default markup and then dynamically add the header, content and footer. jQM should then correctly interprete the markup and enhance it accordingly.

Comment: Well, if I wrap $('body').html(mainView.render().el) in pageinit, nothing happens then. I'm rendering MainView well after the page has loaded.

Comment: page loaded and jQuery Mobile pageinit are two very different events. You can likely render your template whenever but you can't dynamically  add content until after pageinit. Honestly, I have no idea what jQM does with an empty DOM.

Comment: It may be treating it as a single page template and then by injecting a `data-role='page'` element, you are creating a multi-page document (with only a single page). Try leaving the `<div data-role='page'>` element in your default markup and only dynamically add the header, content and footer.

Comment: Leaving `<div data-role='page'>` in place did the trick. If you want to edit your answer to include this, I'll mark that as the answer.